# Clear listbox when new tab selected

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, tabcontrol

I am trying to clear the contents of a listbox when a new tab is seleced. Here is what I got, but nothing happens.

```
 private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["entryTab"])
        {
            readBox.Items.Clear();
            reminderBox.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an asp.net project?

Comment: If it is, try setting AutoPostBack="True" in your tabControl1. If not, you'll need to post more details.
If you put a break point on the "if" statement does it trigger?

Comment: No it is C#. Do I need an eventhandler?

Comment: Asp.Net projects can be written in C# too, but I guess this is a windows forms or WPF solution

Comment: Yes it is sorry I am new to this. The bellow answer got it too work. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your form load

```
   tabControl1.Selecting += new TabControlCancelEventHandler(tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm. I had tried doing something like this earlier, but I think I was using the EventHandler and it would keep giving me errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this set null to DataSource 

private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["entryTab"])
        {
            readBox.DataSource = null;
            reminderBox.DataSource  = null;
        }
    }
```